# How can I determine the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(n+2)-\log(n)}{n^a}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

By hypothesis, $a >0.$

The sum is definitely positive and it verifies the necessary condition for convergence.

I checked on Wolfram Alpha and I got that it converges by the comparison test

My attempt:

I changed the sum to
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\log(\frac{n+2}{n})}{n^a}$

Then

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\log(1+\frac{2}{n})}{n^a}$

So I thought that $\log\left(1+\dfrac{2}{n}\right)$ $\backsim$ $\dfrac{2}{n}$

Thus finally the sum became

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{n^{a+1}}$ that converges for any $a >0.$

My question is: can I do this:  $\log\left(1+\dfrac{2}{n}\right) \backsim$ $\dfrac{2}{n}$ ?

Comment: Yup. Look at the Taylor series.

Comment: Hint. In general, you have that $\log(1+x) \sim x$ when $x$ is in the neighborhood of 0.

Comment: $$ \log(n+2)-\log(n) =\int^{n+2}_{n}\frac1x \, dx   \lt \int^{n+2}_{n}\frac1n \, dx =\dfrac{2}{n}$$

Comment: @çiçek I know that, but in this case is $n$ in the neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: No $n$ tends to infinity which implies that $\frac{2}{n}$ tends to zero

Comment: Thank you, I got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\log(\frac{n+2}{n})}{n^a} = \frac{n\log(\frac{n+2}{n})}{n^{a+1}} = \frac{\log(1+\frac{2}{n})^n}{n^{a+1}} \le \frac2{n^{a+1}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can: it's a general result that two series with *positive* equivalent general terms both converge or both diverge.